# How can I speed up recovery from "shaken"?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I just took down the Assassin's stronghold. It was a *very* long mission (25 turns), so despite everyone being fully rested at the beginning of the mission, my entire squad was tired and two-thirds was shaken or wounded, leaving me with only one available soldier above the rank of Lieutenant, and no available specialists.

I'm a bit worried about this. I don't mind doing a few missions with my B-squad, but I have a retaliation strike coming up in 2 weeks that will have chrysalids in it. I'd *really* prefer to have my medic and Bladestorm ranger for that.

The timer on "shaken" will last just slightly longer than the retaliation timer as-is. Staffing the Infirmary has no effect, and scanning at Templar HQ doesn't seem to do much to it. How can I reduce the time that soldiers need to recover from this?

Comment: Pre-WOTC, shaken status would be cancelled (or have a chance to be cancelled?) if the soldier went on a mission without getting shot or panicking (e.g. psionic attack). I'm not sure if this is unchanged in WOTC, I would think it is but I haven't explicitly confirmed it yet.

Comment: @Flater WotC's shaken status is basically, if a soldier is *too* tired, then they can't go on missions for significant time. Yes, it's completely different from the vanilla version, and I was anticipating that someone would get it confused :P

Comment: @Flater Also, vanilla recovery was having them get a kill on a mission where they aren't wounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [templar resistance order](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Resistance_Orders) called Noble Cause that can boost the will recovery speed of all soldiers by 20%.

Unfortunately, you can only assign this at the end of each month so it may not be possible in your situation.

Comment: It's the thought that counts, but I actually got past this a while ago. (And for the record, the problem that I would have had wouldn't be the end-of-month thing, it would be that I had low influence with the Templars at the time.)

Comment: Nice catch. I wasn't aware of that resistance order.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge you cannot increase recovery speed of "shaken" status.

However, I will try to explain why soldiers are extra likely to be fatigued after a stronghold mission.

This status is based on the 'will' stat, which decreases when soldiers come into contact with enemies, or get wounds. You can track their will loss in battles with [this mod](http://sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1134266810).

According to [some guy in a forum](http://268500/discussions/0/1474221865192094656):

> A soldier is considered ready after a mission if his current will is better then 67% of maximum will. Tired is 33-66% and shaken is below 33%.

Importantly, Chosen strongholds count as **two missions** (remember the load screen for the elevator) in terms of allowable will loss. Will loss is capped at 33% of maximum per mission, so 66% of total can possibly be lost during a stronghold mission.

To conclude, the only cure for 'shaken' status is prevention. Watch out for soldiers just above the 67% will cutoff, and consider not taking them on stronghold missions.

Comment: Well, my full squad started with full will…

Comment: Is it possible that the chosen had the 'brutal' trait that lowers will?

Comment: Would that show up in the list of strengths and weaknesses?

Comment: Yep. Same as the others.

Comment: Then no, it's not possible.